# how to find the count of letter 't' in the below paragraph mentioned using php

Tags: php

```
$a='Would you like to have responses to your questions sent to you via email'

for($a as $b=>c){

}
```

Kindly give me the solution

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Comment: "Kindly give me the solution". No. You try first.

Comment: `for ($a as $b=>$c)` is for iterating over arrays, not strings.

Comment: @Barmar No, that kind of loop does not exist in php.

Comment: And even if it does exist, it's `foreach`, not `for`.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php echo substr_count($a, 't'); ?>
```

Comment: @VinothKumarB You should mark this answer as solution if it helped you. There's a tick on left-hand side of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's **a** solution, though not necessarily the best

```
$letterCount = array_count_values(
    str_split(strtolower($a))
);
$tCount = (isset($letterCount['t'])) ? $letterCount['t'] : 0;
```

Comment: Definitely not the best. You want to count one letter, so first count every letter?

Comment: I don't believe in spoonfeeding __that__ completely, perhaps just hoping that some response before it got closed would persuade the OP to at least try working on something better himself

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = preg_match_all('/t/', $str);
```

Comment: Using `preg_match_all` to count substring occurrences is really odd. Also it's 3-4 times slower than `substr_count`: http://ideone.com/iapbjl or http://codepad.viper-7.com/7pgCNh

Comment: Sure, `substr_count` certainly is the way to go. Just adding variety. :) This here is good for doing the search case-insensitively though if needed.

Answer (score 0):

check this one

```
<?php

$a = 'Would you like to have responses to your questions sent to you via email';

$t_explod = explode('t', strtolower($a));

echo count($t_explod) - 1;
?>
```

Comment: Works, but seems like a pretty convoluted way to do it.